# Sencha Listener Onchange no run

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

hello I am using sencha for the first time here I am using the onchange listener in the numberfield I tried the onchange listener did not work at all and could not process calculations when changing data, please help

CODE SENCHA

```
 {
            id: "total_payment",
            props: {
                bind: {
                    value: "{sum_acc_tra_ap_payment_detail.ap_payment_amt}"
                },
                listeners: {
                    change: function (field, newvalue, oldvalue) {
                        var payment_total = parseFloat(Ext.getCmp("acc_tra_ap_payment").getValues()["payment_total"]);
                        var total_payment = parseFloat(Ext.getCmp("acc_tra_ap_payment").getValues()["total_payment"]);
                        var hasile = payment_total+ total_payment;
                        Ext.getCmp("acc_tra_ap_payment").getFields("payment_total").setValue(hasile);
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing a field that is bound to data in the viewModel you can bind the total also to a value in the viewModel.

Here is a fiddle: [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/39iq)

you could also use a formula that binds to the paymentAmount field.

Here is the documentation for the view models: [ViewModel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.0/guides/application_architecture/view_models_data_binding.html)

The fiddle I put together is using Extjs 7.3 and the Modern toolkit. It is always helpful if you include the version of extjs and toolkit (modern or classic) you are using, you will also get an answer that is more tailored to your question.